# How to create template POCO class

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, repository, poco

currently i am creating POCO classes for each table. Can we create 1 **POCO template (template repository)** that will save all types of objects. Wo don`t have to create class for each table. Is there any way of doing this with 1 template class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this link could help you use generic repository pattern for saving all POCO classes with one generic class if that's your question.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application